# why mongodb in node express cannot set result to outside variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So this question might be a javascript concept question. but I cannot figure out why

I retrieve data from mongodb however, I cannot define _res variable to become the result.
console.log(_res) will return undefined.

Does anyone know why? and how to make it work as it should be?

```js
app.route('/').get(function(req,res){
 let _res;
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err;
   var dbo = db.db("vm");
   var query = {};
    dbo.collection("vm").find(query).toArray( function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var vmData = JSON.stringify (result)
      _res = vmData
      db.close();

      res.render('index.ejs', {
   vmData: vmData
   });
    });
 });
 console.log(_res)
});
```

Comment: It seems `MongoClient.connect` is being executed asynchronously and when you call `console.log(_res)` , `MongoClient.connect` has still not finished executing and assigning value to `_res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb query is an asynchronous operation. The console statement is executed before the query has been processed.
You define `_res` outside which is undefined outside, so the same value is consoled outside.

```
app.route('/').get(function(req,res){
    let _res;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("vm");
        var query = {};
        dbo.collection("vm")
          .find(query)
          .toArray((err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            var vmData = JSON.stringify (result)
            _res = vmData
            db.close();
            console.log('Inside', _res) // <---Should give you correct result
            res.render('index.ejs', {
            vmData: vmData
          });
        });
    });
    console.log('Outside', _res);
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to wait for the async. query to be done?

Comment: Node is designed in a such a way such that it is non blocking in nature. The asynchronous methods are handled using a callback mechanism. What is the use case you want to handle? @andrew

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Not really having a specific question need to handle. Just wondering how this works and how can I do it differently

Comment: Great. You can get more information about node and how it is non blocking in nature here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en

Answer (score 0):

The code is being executed asynchronously due to which when the console.log is executed the _res is undefined.
Try to execute your logic when the asyn methods are being executed.

```js
app.route('/').get(function(req,res){
 let _res;
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err;
   var dbo = db.db("vm");
   var query = {};
    dbo.collection("vm").find(query).toArray( function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var vmData = JSON.stringify (result)
      _res = vmData;
                    console.log(_res);
      db.close();

      res.render('index.ejs', {
   vmData: vmData
   });

    });
 });     
});
```